# How to categorize a continuous variable based on its correlation with another continuous variable?

Tags: r, correlation, linear

Two continuous variables are correlated but not in linear relation. How can I categorize the Independent variable to make two or more groups based on the correlation.
For example age is correlated with depression. How can I split age in a way to find the highest depressed age group.
I tried this using `R` and `iris` dataset, but looping take time and don't give me what I really want.

```
attach(iris)
cor(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)

a<-integer()
for (i in Sepal.Width){
b<-cor(Sepal.Length[Sepal.Width>i],Sepal.Width[Sepal.Width>i])
a<-c(a,b)
}
sort(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

This goal is inappropriate.  Categorization should play no role.  Study the *continuous* relationship between the two continuous variables using a scatterplot and for example the *loess* nonparametric smoother.

Comment: I want to identify the highest correlated subgroup of a variable with another variable. Can you please explain why doing this is inappropriate ?   for example the highly correlated age group with depression or with response to drug x.

Comment: See the Information Loss chapter in Biostatistics for Biomedical Research at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat .  What will shed light on the subject is to relate age with depression or age with drug response, continuously.  The phenomenon you are studying has no discontinuities.